# How to delete white corners

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

how to get rid of there white corners after adding the backround?

Edit: It's a dialog pop up

It looks like this:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/color_choose_dialog"
```

//and here's code for the background:

```
`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid 
 android:color="@color/md_theme_light_onPrimary" />
 <corners
    android:radius="30dp" />
 <padding
    android:left="20dp"
    android:top="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:bottom="20dp" />
 </shape>
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: It's not clear where do you use this layout; is it a fragment, dialog, dialogFragment...

Comment: it's a dialog. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change background color from white to transparent. Corners' white color will become invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a card instead of using ConstraintLayout and use

`app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"`

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
    ....

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    
    //remove white space
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    alertDialog.show();
```